# node.js: req.next is not a function

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I've tried to deploy the project to google cloud platform. The code is working fine on my local machine. However, I'm getting the following error on gcloud.

```
TypeError: req.next is not a function
at done (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:955)
at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:641)
at EventEmitter.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591)
at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960)
at (/app/routes/posts.js:15)
at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510)
at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612)
at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691)
at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138)
at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/mongolass/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (async.js:17)
at runCallback (timers.js:666)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639)
at processImmediate (timers.js:611)
```

routes/posts.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var author = req.query.author;

  PostModel.getPosts(author)
    .then(function (posts) {
      res.render('posts', { //line 15
        posts: posts
      });
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

getPosts function:

```
getPosts: function getPosts(author) {
    var query = {};
    if (author) {
      query.author = author;
    }
    return Post
      .find(query)
      .populate({ path: 'author', model: 'User' })
      .sort({ _id: -1 })
      .addCreatedAt()
      .addCommentsCount()
      .contentToHtml()
      .exec();
  },
```

Comment: Is your version of node.js, express, etc. exactly the same as your development box?

Comment: this might not be a gcloud issue, try running locally with NODE_ENV=production and see if it reproduces

Comment: node -v: v6.10.2   "dependencies": {
    "config-lite": "1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "1.3.2",
    "ejs": "2.5.2",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "express-formidable": "1.0.0",
    "express-session": "1.14.2",
    "express-winston": "2.0.0",
    "marked": "0.3.6",
    "moment": "2.15.2",
    "mongolass": "2.3.1",
    "objectid-to-timestamp": "1.3.0",
    "sha1": "1.1.1",
    "winston": "2.2.0"
  }

Comment: I've tested <NODE_ENV=production supervisor --harmony server.js> and it works fine.

Comment: How does your app.yaml look like? Are all URLs there well defined? What happens if you replace function(req, res, next) with function(req, res)?

Comment: @rluo Since you have solved your own issue it is recommended to post the solution as the answer to this question to better help the community.

Comment: I have the same issue